# Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new to spring boot and just started exploring it .I came across this issue where intellij ide shows this error in pom.xml .I fail to understand as to why this is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-boot-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-boot-tutorial</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

It will be really helpful if someone can enlighten as to how these dependencies issues happen in spring boot and how they can be traced.
Note i had a similar issue with spring-boot-maven-plugin so i just added the version code below it to make it work .The same addition of the version didn't work for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: Try reopening IDE and use `mvn install && spring-boot:run`. Please let me know if that will resolve your issue

Comment: I did invalidate cache from intellij and those red marks don't exist any more in pom.xml.

Comment: @Reborn  i have another question as how compilation works because even with those red marks in pom.xml ,compilation happened .

Comment: If you see red marks in the pom.xml even after installing dependencies, then there might be another issue. Double check on how you import the project ( it should be imported as Maven). Afterwards, make sure you right click on the project and select 'Sync the project;

Comment: _This error_ you forgot to actually include the error.

Answer (score 6):

Reloading the project might help.
Steps

1. Right click on the project
2. Go to the "maven" option
3. Click on "Reload Project"

Comment: If this does not work, then try File -> Invalidate Caches -> Select all options.